# postgreSQL create rule on select where clause

Tags: postgresql

I would like some assistance on the syntax on creating a rule that includes a where clause.

Here is  what I have so far

```
CREATE RULE CodeRetrieve AS  
    ON SELECT TO RC.Code from RC WHERE RC.CODEID = FromQuery.CODEID
    DO INSTEAD  
    RCAA.Code from RCAA WHERE RCAA.CODEID = FromQuery.CODEID
```

Basically, by default I want to redirect the query from one table to another and return the results from the RCAA table.

Reason? To avoid going thru the code in a gazillion places and changing the query.  Just wanted to experiment with changing the code in one place, i.e. a database rule.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just create a view named `RC` which selects from `RCAA`?

Answer (score 1):

To redirec query from old table to new table maybe you don't need a rule but only some DDL and plane old sql.
If you rename your table RC (for example in "_RC") and create view RC as select * from RCAA (eventually with a "where" filter) your gazillion lines of code need no change for the select query.
in case of need of action query you can add a rule on the RC view.